# Is it possible to search a view of views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View that is a list of users. One of the fields is an Include View field.

This field includes another View which has a contextual filter for the user, and shows the node that was created in a certain month by that user (if it exists).

These nodes have categories and I would like to have a filter on the main view where I can sort out which users have a node in a certain category. But due to the nature of included Views, I can't find a filter that works.

Is there a way to search a view that is an Include View?

Answer (score 0):

Under Advanced (located on the right side), for Relationships add `Content Authored`

[image]

Then in Filter (located on the left side) add `Content Type` and expose the filter.

[image]